# OfficeJs `Cannot read property 'Version' of null` Zone.js error

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are developing an OfficeJs add-in for use in the Outlook Web App (OWA) using Angular (V6.x atm.)
Angular depends on the `zone.js` Javascript library which we include in our `polyfills.ts` file.

It seems that OfficeJs uses a method (or álso depends on `zone.js`) that is causing the following error (which we comfortably have been ignoring for months together with the many other warnings and errors the OWA generates):

> polyfills.js:4888 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Version' of null
>       at Object.callback (outlook-web-16.01.js:9)
>       at rt (outlook-web-16.01.js:9)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:5117)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (polyfills.js:4884)
>       at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.js:5192)
>       at invokeTask (polyfills.js:6236)
>       at globalZoneAwareCallback (polyfills.js:6262)

in `outlook-web-16.01.js:9`, this is the line where this error originates:

OSF.DDA.WAC.Delegate.version=**i.Version**;r=i.Error

I was not able to reverse engineer what OfficeJs is trying to do, but it seems that the method where this goes wrong is located on this line:

`https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/blob/release/dist/office.debug.js#L1594

This happens deterministically when we use the `Office.ui.messageParent` method to send stringified JSON data from a dialog back to the parent add-in.

Unfortunately the stack trace does not give us anything more to investigate:

[image]

Comment: Can you pleaes help me out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53425063/how-to-define-excel-using-microsoft-office-js-in-angular-6

Comment: But does it impact your application in any way?

Comment: @BrianClink Well, no, that's why we have been ignoring it. But it's annoying, distracting and I want to know how to solve it, if at all possible.