# How to define Excel using microsoft office-js in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, office-js, office-addins, office-js-helpers

I am following this [site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/office-js/v/0.1.0-beta.2?activeTab=readme#use-office-javascript-api-in-nodejs-application) to integrate office js

On declaring like this:

`import * as Excel from '@microsoft/office-js/excel'`
It's showing compile time error:

> Cannot find module '@microsoft/office-js/excel'

On declaring like this:

`declare var Excel: any`

It's showing run time error:

> ERROR ReferenceError: Excel is not defined

Please suggest how to declare it. I need to use it like this:

```
Excel.run(session, (context){
   ...
});
```

Comment: A hack that might temporarily help you (until you find a better solution) is declaring the 'Excel' object so that type checking is circumvented. You can do this by adding a script tag with office.js and adding this `declare const Excel: any;
declare const Office: any;` below the import statements in the javascript file.

Comment: Already tried that. Didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install office type definition:

```
npm install --save @types/office-js
```

In tsconfig.app.json you add:

```
"types": [
    "office-js"
]
```

In main.ts you bootstrap app as:

```
    Office.initialize = function () {
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
};
```

In index.html you add:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>
```

After that you should be able to write something like this in your angular service:

```
  getExtension(): string {
    if (Office.context.host === Office.HostType.Word) {
      return '.docx';
    } else if  (Office.context.host === Office.HostType.Excel) {
      return '.xlsx';
    } else if (Office.context.host === Office.HostType.PowerPoint) {
      return '.pptx';
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Here you can find a sample of angular office-js project:

[Angular office-js sample project](https://github.com/dgrudenic/angular-office-addin)

It is Angular 6 build with Angular CLI version 6.0.8

Comment: In which service shall I add getExtension()

Comment: you add this in your angular service or angular component.

Comment: Ths is giving an error:   ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'host' of undefined

Comment: Sorry I thought you already installed types see improved answer

Comment: Yeah not sure where the problem is might be with office manifest or something. I created new angular sample project https://github.com/dgrudenic/angular-office-addin you can take a look there.

Comment: Thanks. Will look into it

Comment: Hi, I have cloned your project. It's showing an error in console:  the server responded with a status of 404 () https://telemetryservice.firstpartyapps.oaspapps.com/telemetryservice/telemetryproxy.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184162/discussion-between-dalibor-grudenic-and-adrita-sharma).

Comment: Has anyone else noticed that this only works for eagerly loaded modules? How can I get it to work for lazy-loaded modules?

Comment: Is it possible to open client side outlook app with formatted mail body in it using angular web app ?